# Model of a fluid through a pipe can't run on openmodelica

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

I'm trying to simulate on OpenModelica, a fluid (here water) that flowh through a pipe with an inlet pressure and temperature. I want to take into account the convective exchange between the wall of the pipe and the fluid, the convective exchange between the wall, the ambient and the conductive exchange in the wall and the properties of the medium that vary in function of the temperature... The check of the model is ok but when I run the simulation I have an error.

Here is my code :

```
model Water_flow

  replaceable package Medium=Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater constrainedby
    Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;
    
  output Modelica.SIunits.MassFlowRate mass_flow_rate=abs(pipe.port_b.m_flow);
     
     
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 318.45, nPorts = 1, p = 14.6e5) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-24, -80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 328.15, nPorts = 1, p = 14e5) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {60, -80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium, redeclare model HeatTransfer=Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.LocalPipeFlowHeatTransfer, T_start = 318.15, allowFlowReversal = false, diameter = 13e-3, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial, height_ab = 0, length = 15, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial, nNodes = 5, use_HeatTransfer = true)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {18, -80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(T_ambient = 290.15, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-84, 84}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection convection annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, -2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k = 358)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-88, -2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature(T = 328.15)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection convection1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-16, -2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature1(T = 328.15) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-16, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.BaseClasses.WallConstProps wallConstProps(T_start = 318.15, area_h = 0.9, c_wall = 420, dT = 283.15, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial, k_wall = 60.5, n = 5, rho_wall = 7850, s = 6e-3) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {18, -44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection convection2 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {18, -2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature2(T = 328.15)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {18, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature3(T = 328.15)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature4(T = 328.15)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {82, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection convection3 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, -2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection convection4 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {82, -2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));

equation
  connect(boundary.ports[1], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-14, -80}, {8, -80}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, boundary1.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{28, -80}, {50, -80}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(const.y, convection.Gc) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-77, -2}, {-60, -2}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(fixedTemperature.port, convection.fluid) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-50, 34}, {-50, 8}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(fixedTemperature.port, convection.fluid) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-50, 34}, {-50, 8}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(fixedTemperature1.port, convection1.fluid) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-16, 34}, {-16, 8}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(const.y, convection1.Gc) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-77, -2}, {-26, -2}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(convection.solid, wallConstProps.heatPort_a[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-50, -12}, {-50, -24}, {18, -24}, {18, -39}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(fixedTemperature2.port, convection2.fluid) annotation(
    Line(points = {{18, 34}, {18, 8}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(convection2.solid, wallConstProps.heatPort_a[3]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{18, -12}, {18, -39}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(const.y, convection2.Gc) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-77, -2}, {8, -2}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(const.y, convection3.Gc) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-76, -2}, {40, -2}, {40, -2}, {40, -2}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(const.y, convection4.Gc) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-76, -2}, {72, -2}, {72, -2}, {72, -2}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(convection3.solid, wallConstProps.heatPort_a[4]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{50, -12}, {50, -24}, {18, -24}, {18, -39}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(convection4.solid, wallConstProps.heatPort_a[5]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{82, -12}, {82, -24}, {18, -24}, {18, -39}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(convection1.solid, wallConstProps.heatPort_a[2]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-16, -12}, {-16, -24}, {18, -24}, {18, -39}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(wallConstProps.heatPort_b, pipe.heatPorts) annotation(
    Line(points = {{18, -49}, {18, -76}}, color = {191, 0, 0}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(fixedTemperature3.port, convection3.fluid) annotation(
    Line(points = {{50, 34}, {50, 8}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(fixedTemperature4.port, convection4.fluid) annotation(
    Line(points = {{82, 34}, {82, 34}, {82, 8}, {82, 8}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")),
    Diagram);
end Water_flow;
```

The error message is in the image.

[image]

If anyone has an idea of what's wrong with the model.

Thanks and have a great day,
Maxime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dymola your code runs but with a lot of warnings. Initializing the pipe pressures makes it run without warnings — for example, `pipe.p_a_start=1460000` and `pipe.p_b_start=1400000`.

Another thing, you *could* declare the convective elements and fixed temperatures as an array like this:

```
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.Convection[pipe.nNodes]  convection
Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature[pipe.nNodes] fixedTemperature(each T = 328.15)
```

That will make your model easier to maintain if you choose another discretization, e.g. `pipe.nNodes=10`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that increasing the number of nodes solved the problem, the simulation finished succesfully. However I got the warning "Warning: maximal number of iteration reached but no root found" . Thanks for your proposition about the array I'll try it